# Letting The Character Traverse Between Art Canvases When There Are Intersecting Sides in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a video game where the character has to travel within literal art canvases (the ones that you use for painting) to reach the end goal.

Note that the "canvas" I am referring is not the UI element, but the actual canvases you would see in real life.

[image: The image below describes the game's core movement mechanics]

I based my code off the concepts of portals. This may not be the most efficient way of dealing with it and I will consider all advices.

This is my current code:

```
public Transform PortalB;
public CharacterController2D Player;
public GameObject PlayerObject;

private GameObject CloneTemporary;

public Queue<GameObject> Clones = new Queue<GameObject>();

private bool isCreated = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Clones.Enqueue(PlayerObject);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // Portal adapts to the player's current position
    if (Player == null) {
        Player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();    
        PlayerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, other.transform.position) > 0.7f) {



            if (!isCreated) {

                CloneTemporary = Instantiate(PlayerObject, new Vector2 (PortalB.position.x, PortalB.position.y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

                Clones.Enqueue(CloneTemporary);

                isCreated = true;
            }

        }

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D other) {
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, other.transform.position) > 0.7f) {
        print(Clones.Count);
        if (Clones.Count > 1) {
            UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(Clones.Dequeue());
        }
    }

    isCreated = false;
}
```

The "original character" will collide with the portal's box collider and create a copy on the other end of the portal. The box collider is annotated in red in the first image below. Note that the sizes are exactly the same.

Note that it technically is not a portal, but since it's a box which brings a character from one place to another, I might as well call it a portal.

Once the original leaves the box collider, it will get deleted, and the clone will then become the "original".

I am using a queue system to determine which "clone" gets deleted first.

There are a few problems with this:

1. It is very inefficient. I have to create portals manually for every intersection point in the canvases. Imagine a level full of canvases, and imagine a game with full of levels...
2. When it touches the portal, a duplicate will get spawned by the original character. There are three characters, but the Clones.Count only registers two.
3. I am not sure how well the code will work for vertical traverses.
4. When the character crosses the portal, it should be able to turn back. In this code, the character would glitch through the floor if he were to turn back and not get deleted by the OnExit function. I suspect this has something to do with the size of the portal, but I can foresee that even if it were to be bigger, the character would immediately disappear if he turns back.
5. I think the OnTriggerEnter function gets activated when the character is teleported on the other side. This might have an effect on the errors I just stated, but it may cause more in the near future. 
   [image: Duplication upon touching and box colliders annotated]

[image: The original leaves the collision box and gets deleted, but the accidental copy still remains]

[image: The current original one touches the portal on the other side and spawns another duplicate]

[image: The current original gets deleted once it crosses over the collider box, but the accidental copy still remains]

Comment: I dont get where there are portals in your images. Could you maybe mark them? Also canvas is a UI element, what does it have to do with all that? I have a strong suspicion you overthought things and make it more complicated than it is.

Comment: Rest easy, OP, you're not overthinking this. It is something that needs much consideration - both from a point of conception and construction. Unfortunately it also requires profound understanding of any engine you choose to do this within. Search for "teleporting" and unity, and read through many different ways of doing this. Don't just settle on the first way that seems to work, as this being a foundational aspect of your game, all choices you make will have ramifications on what you can and can also do, and not do, around the mechanic and other events/occurrences and inputs etc.

Comment: Have you considered not deleting the gameobjects and disable them instead? this means that you could simply instantiate a gameobject (player(clone)) in each window(disabled), then enable this clone at the desired location and disable the one who entered, you can tweak this and likely make it work like your desired concept.

Comment: @yes Thanks for your input. I will make the necessary edit for clarity. I will make some comments about it here though. Canvases are literal canvases, as in, the things you use as a medium in visual, not the UI element. Am I overthinking things? I do not know. I can laugh about it someday once I see how potentially simple it may be.

Comment: @Confused I definitely went ahead of myself when I started this project. I understand the core mechanics and the limitations it will place in my game, thus, I have kept my game fairly simple. I plan to only have moving canvases (much like moving platforms) and a switch. I have explored various alternatives to this mechanic, but this specific mechanic (where I spawn a clone and delete the original) is the only one which allows for a smooth transition between canvases. Though I am glad to take in any further advice on this approach.

Comment: @Skdy I have considered that, but now that you mention it, it may work. My only concern with it is that it may put up an unnecessary strain on the computer. For example, if I were to have 10 canvases, I would need to put a clones in each one, which would mean I would have to create 10 different clones. My current queue system, which destroys the old clone immediately after it is out of sight, works around this issue. But both ways have their own complications, perhaps the ones present in this method will be easier to tackle. I will definitely try out your method. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think it's fine to do any and all building you can to make something work... early on, so long as you're prepared to completely rebuild once you realise how you should have done it ;)

Comment: More seriously, I think you simply need two instances of your hero, and to put him where you need him in both canvases, and then use masking as appropriate where and when he transitions. When the second is not needed, push it off the screen somewhere unseen, and deactivate it. Use a switch to work between the two instances, treating either one as active, as required, when required, and the other as the transitioning to target, before it becomes active, at which point the other becomes the previously active, prepared to become the target again, as and where and when needed.

Comment: btw, it seems like a super cool game idea!!! And I can't highly enough commend you for coming up with something unique!!! Well done!!!

Comment: Sadly I have no experience in 2D, so if you want a PoC as answer that will take me a bit of reading, but like @Confused said aswell, I think what you really want is a spritemask aligned with the portals and simply deactivate the old hero and activate a 2nd instance. Dont destroy the old one tho, when it goes through the next portal, simply reuse the first one again. Finally, I also want to go along saying its an awesome idea +1